# Group membership not transferred from server to client

Tags: nis

I have a Suse Version 11.1.0.21 Server with home-partitions for every user and shared partitions for different groups. Groups and group rights (3775) are defined. When the group member is logged in at the server, he is allowed to write on the partition. NIS is installed.

I have an Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS client. The group member is not allowed to write on the commonly used partition, when he is not the owner of the directory. The group rights are set to 3775. If the group member is the owner of the directory, writing is possible.

There is something interesting:

executing the command at the client:

```
ypcat group
```

provides the expected output:

```
groupname:x:1003:groupmember1,groupmember2
```

but executing the commands at the client
`groups` and `id`

by using the following command:

```
groupmember1@client:~$ groups
```

the group membership is missing

Local user accounts do not exist but only a root account.

The end of /etc/passwd file at the client looks:

```
+::::::
```

The end of /etc/group file at the client looks:

```
+:::
```

Does anybody have an idea where the problem is?

Comment: What's in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?  Has `groupmember1` logged out and in since you made the change in NIS (group memberships are only picked up at login time)?